# Should the preprocessor arithmetic match the architecture targeted by the compilation?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, preprocessor

Let say I have this preprocessor check:

```
#if(-6 & 5)
    #error "No 2's complement signed int"
#endif
```

What would happen if I cross compiled from, say, a two's complement machine toward a one's complement machine. Would the compiler use the arithmetic of the target machine, or the one of the compiling machine ?

Thanks

Comment: C++20 requires two's complement.

Comment: Just use `static_assert` and you can be sure the target architecture is used in addition to avoiding the use of the preprocessor `static_assert((-6 & 5) == 0, "No 2's complement signed int");`

Comment: Literal constants would be generated in the target machine's format.

Comment: Ok, for C++ and using static_assert, but "what if" I use C. My question is looking for a language lawyer about preprocessor not a workaround

Comment: @stark can we talk about literal constants at the proprocessor stage like we could in C code ?

Comment: I suspect that the standard says nothing about cross-compiling, and you would have to refer to the manual/documentation of whatever compiler you are using. Also C has `_Static_assert`.

Comment: AFAIK, (almost?) all nowadays processors use 2's complement for signed integers. You might succeed to find one weird embedded processor still used today on old machines but no mainstream one (eg. PC, smartphones, servers, etc.). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations : "*As IC technology advanced, two's complement technology was adopted in virtually all processors*".

Comment: FYI: C also has `static_assert` (or `_Static_assert` if you don't want to include `assert.h`)

Comment: @JérômeRichard while that's true for CPU architecture desktops and most handheld\embedded, not universally true. A number of avionics, literally everything related to video encoding (especially H264\H265), things  like industrial data acquisition systems aren't complement of two. E.g. most of the very last one are using least-significant bit for a sign. Funny thing..in absolute numbers those devices are more numerous than those with complement of two. Every camera, including one in phone, for example. It's just number of  people who can work with their firmware code is catastrophically low.

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages. Pick one language and delete the other tag.

Comment: The C and C++ standards do not define semantics in terms of a “target machine” or a “compiling machine.” There is a translation environment and an execution environment. These environments are determined by the developers of the C or C++ implementation. Notably, they may use software to perform calculations that differ from native hardware instructions.

Comment: Note that "Should..." is a very different question to "Does ...". E.g. a preprocessor should use arbitrary precision "big numbers" but sadly that isn't what the preprocessor does.

Comment: Etienne M, Aside: alternate 2's complement test: `#if INT_MIN == -INT_MAX`. Of course that obliges a `<*.h>` file.

Comment: please unaccept my answer. I'd like to delete it because it is wrong

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Are you talking about the data formats or the processor used? I am curious about that (especially camera devices). I cannot find any information about this. I though cameras in smartphones uses cheap ARM processors. Can you share some link for camera devices?

Comment: @JérômeRichard Smartphone cameras are more "dumb", but.. both cameras and radio transceivers are both processors, enhancers and encoders, so data formats used are related to way device works and it's a software-controlled device. Your ARM CPU is doing only high-level work with data  and ARM is best because its way to work with data registers in various modes. The matrix itself is a form of SoC. Strict time constraint make it a real-time application and it is software-controlled. In case of industrial data acquisition it's also a data format transferred between systems

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C 2018 6.10.1 4 says, for evaluation of expressions in `#if` and `#elif` directives:

> … For the purposes of this token conversion and evaluation, all signed integer types and all unsigned integer types act as if they have the same representation as, respectively, the types `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t` defined in the header `<stdint.h>`…

These types are of course used during program execution, so their behaviors are those of the execution environment.

Comment: The type is required to be target-dependent, while the numeric value for a character constant is not required to be target-dependent: both `#if 'x' == 17` and `if ('x' == 13)` may be evaluated to true.